# How to get a structured JSON output with Scrapy?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am a newbie to Python and recently I am trying to use Scrapy to scrape a website with multiple pages and below is the code segment from my "spider.py"

```
    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        tuples = sel.xpath('//*[td[@class = "caption"]]')
        items = []

        for tuple in tuples:
            item = DataTuple()

            keyTemp = tuple.xpath('td[1]').extract()[0]
            key = html2text.html2text(keyTemp).rstrip()
            valueTemp = tuple.xpath('td[2]').extract()[0]
            value = html2text.html2text(valueTemp).rstrip()

            item[key] = value
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

By running the code with the command:

```
scrapy crawl dumbSpider -o items.json -t json
```

It would give out:

```
{"a":"a-Value"},
{"b":"b-Value"},
{"c":"c-Value"},
{"a":"another-a-Value"},
{"b":"another-b-Value"},
{"c":"another-c-Value"}
```

But I actually want something like:

```
{"a":"a-Value", "b":"b-Value", "c":"c-Value"},
{"a":"another-a-Value", "b":"another-b-Value", "c":"another-c-Value"}
```

I tried a few ways to tweak the spider.py for example using a temporary list to store all "item" of a single webpage and then append the temporary list to "items" but somehow it doesn't work.

**updated**: the indentation is fixed.

Comment: Consider to create new two dictionaries in your case- first one will be filled with your subdictionaries until it will find that particular key like `a` is already there. If this situation would occur- create new dictionary and do the same.

Comment: @PatNowak thanks for the comment! however the data shown on that site is too flexible to be monitored. I actually have no way to know when am I approaching to the end of the scraping in a certain page.

Comment: is it always in order? I mean it always comes by 3 and you want the first 3, then the other 3 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Below I've done a quick mockup of how I'd recommend doing this so long as you know the number of TD per page. You can take some or all of it as you see fit. This is probably over-engineered for your question (Sorry!); you could take just the chunk_by_numbers bit and be done....

A few things to note:

1) avoid using 'tuple' as a variable name, as it's also an internal keyword

2) learn to use generators/built-ins, as they'll be faster and lighter if you're doing ALOT of sites at once (see parse_to_kv and chunk_by_number below)

3) try to isolate parsing logic so if it changes, you can easily swap out at one place (see extract_td below)

4) your function does not use 'self', so you should use the @staticmethod decorator and remove this parameter from the function

5) at the moment the output is a dict, but you could import json and dump it if you need a JSON object

```
def extract_td(item, index):
    # extract logic for my websites which allows extraction
    # of either a key or value from a table data
    # returns a string representation of item[index]
    # this is very page/tool specific!
    td_as_str = "td[%i]" % index
    val = item.xpath(td_as_str).extract()[0]
    return html2text.html2text(val).rstrip()

def parse_to_kv(xpaths):
    # returns key, value pairs from the given
    # this is also page specific
    for xpath in xpaths:
        yield extract_td(xpath, 0), extract_td(xpath, 1)

def chunk_by_number(alist, num):
    # splices alist into chunks of num size.
    # This is a very generic, reusable operation
    for chunk in list(zip(*(iter(alist),) * num)):
        yield chunk

def parse(response, td_per_page):
    # extracts key/value pairs based on the table datas in response
    # yields lists of length td_per_page which contain these key/value extractions
    # this is very specific based on our parse patterns
    sel = Selector(response)
    tuples = sel.xpath('//*[td[@class = "caption"]]')
    kv_generator = parse_to_kv(tuples)

    for page in chunk_by_number(kv_generator, td_per_page):
        print dict(page)
```